# XAMPP Doesn't Start: SSH Not Accesible

Tags: php, mysql, apache, xampp

So basically, i'm trying to learn how to use XAMPP to make a php server with MySQL. When I try to start it however, the start button doesn't work. The button is greyed out for some reason.

An image of the control menu: https://i.stack.imgur.com/j7bog.jpg

When I try to start the server from the general tab, it shows a yellow dot meaning it is starting (Image here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/lCPFH.jpg) and after it is done, it shows this error message: https://i.stack.imgur.com/u0BKO.jpg

The error I get when I click show details: cannot start stack: ssh not accessible

The Log:

```
INFO: Starting "XAMPP" stack
ERROR: Error starting "XAMPP" stack: cannot start stack: ssh not accessible`
```

I have tried everything; I tried reinstalling, I tried deleting my ~/.bitnami folder, but nothing works.

Answer (score 1):

I stumbled upon this thread last night, and learned that it was because I had used `CHMOD 777`, which unfortunately broke `XAMPP`.

So wanted to share how I 'solved' this (rescued my files) without having a recent Time Machine backup in case it might be helpful for others.

```
Step 1: 
Copy the virtual XAMPP machine (machine.qcow2) in terminal

‘$ cd .bitnami/stackman/machines/xampp/vm’

Now '$ open .' and move the 'machine.qcow2' file to e.g. downloads.

Step 2:
Delete the .bitnami folder.

Step 3:
Delete and re-install XAMPP.

Step 4:
Launch XAMPP and mount the image, then move machine.qcow2 file into '/opt/lamp/htdocs' using Finder.

Step 5: 
Install qemu-utils and p7zip-full

'$ sudo apt-get install qemu-utils'
'$ sudo apt-get install p7zip-full'

Step 6:
Go into the 'htdocs' directory and convert machine.qcow2 to machine.iso with qemu

'$ cd /opt/lampp/htdocs'
'$ qemu-img convert image.qcow2 image.iso'

Step 7: 
'Unzip' the .iso file

'$ 7z x image.iso'
```

That's it! If you `'$ ls'` now, you'll see your old files!

I then used `7z` to make a Zip-backup folder with the old files, moved the `7z` to my desktop, deleted and re-installed `XAMPP`. Cleared the new 'htdocs' and unzipped the file again.

This took me about half a night to figure out, so hopefully it will be useful for someone!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need to change the ports. Sometimes different programs use the same ports and it doesnt work properly. Try changing the ports.

[Changing ports Xammp](https://www.jsolucioncreativa.com/disenoweb-internet/cambiar-los-puertos-de-apache-y-mysql-en-xampp-correctamente/)